# How to get http response in node.js?

Tags: node.js

node.js: 6.9.4

I wrote codes like below, but it does not work what i want.

```
var request = require(‘superagent’);
var url = “https://XXX”

  var login_id=“YYY”
var password=“ZZZ”

function get_token(url,login_id,password){
  request
    .post(login_url)
    .set(‘X-XXX-HEADER, ‘xxx’)
.set(‘X-yyy-HEADER, ‘yyy’)
.type('form')
    .send({login_id: login_id, password: password})
    .end(function(err, res){
      console.log(res.text); // show response
      return res.text;
    })
}

var auth = get_token(login_url, login_id, password);
console.log(auth); // show undefined
```

I want to create function to return response data, and use like that.

```
// define function get_token

  res = get_token(login_url, login_id, password);

// procedure that return token with parsing res

function getXXX(otherurl, token)
```

how can I do?
  In node.js what’s the good way?

Answer (score 0):

You Should use callback

```
var request = require(‘superagent’);
var url = “https://XXX”

var login_id=“YYY”
var password=“ZZZ”

function get_token(url, login_id, password, callback){
    request
        .post(login_url)
        .set(‘X-XXX-HEADER, ‘xxx’)
        .set(‘X-yyy-HEADER, ‘yyy’)
        .type('form')
        .send({login_id: login_id, password: password})
        .end(function(err, res){
            console.log(res.text); // show response

            return callback(err, res);
        })
}


get_token(login_url, login_id, password, function (err, result) {
    var auth = result.text;
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I try to use callback.

Answer (score 0):

Change get_token to `return request..` and change  `get_token(login_url, login_id, password).then(console.log);

You will need to read and take your time learning about JavaScript Promises.